# Paytm Test Api key not showing

Tags: next.js, paytm

I am interested in utilizing Paytm as a platform to facilitate transactions with customers, utilizing the Paytm service for payment collection. However, I am currently encountering an issue as the API key necessary for this integration is not being generated as expected. Despite having gone through the process of generating the API key, I am still facing difficulties.

[image]

Comment: Can you add all the relevant code for debugging?

Comment: I also facing this issue